# How do I change nodejs admin hashed password or add another admin account?

Tags: mysql, node.js, phpmyadmin

I have a node.js application I'm working on, unfortunately a wrong email address was used for the admin account and we can't remember the password.

The hashed key type used is bcrypt. $2a$09$OczLcHx7lZQd1cgbLLmTrewUUx.nwEoZAuDembLxXI00mVEobyQZ6

I would like to know if there is a way to change the password or add a new admin account entirely.

Things I've done to resolve the admin login issue.

I have tried modifying the password from the phpmyadmin MySQL table and also changing the admin email address, but the nodejs app still doesn't recognize the changes.

This is my password.js file

```
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const db = require("../models/db");
exports.hashPassword = (password) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const newHashPassword = bcrypt.hash(password, 9);
        resolve(newHashPassword)
    })
}


exports.comparePassword = (password, hashPassword) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const same = bcrypt.compareSync(password, hashPassword);
        resolve(same)
    })
}


//SAVE RESET PASSWORD TOKEN TO DB
exports.saveResetPasswordIntoDB = (obj) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.query("INSERT INTO f_password_reset_token SET ?", obj, (err, data) => {
            if (err) reject(err)
            else resolve(data)
        })
    })
}

//DELETE USER RESET PASSWORD TOKENs TO DB
exports.deleteResetPasswordByUserId = (userId) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.query("DELETE FROM f_password_reset_token WHERE token_user = ?", parseInt(userId), (err, data) => {
            if (err) reject(err)
            else resolve(data)
        })
    })
}

//DELETE ALL RESET PASSWORD TOKENs TO DB
exports.deleteAllResetPassword = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.query("DELETE FROM f_password_reset_token", (err, data) => {
            if (err) reject(err)
            else resolve(data)
        })
    })
}


//CHECK IF USER HAS A TOKEN
exports.checkPasswordTokenByUserId = (userId,token) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.query("SELECT * FROM f_password_reset_token WHERE token_user = ? AND token_code = ?", [parseInt(userId), token], (err, data) => {
            if (err) reject(err)
            else resolve(data[0])
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's not in production, why not just temporarily override the `bcrypt.compareSync` function within the `comparePassword` function? According to [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) the `bcrypt.compareSync` function returns true or false so that would be a quick n' dirty oneliner that could allow you to bypass the password check. It's not the nicest way, and success is not guaranteed, and you certainly should not do this in production but It could help you get around the wrong password so you can login and reset/change your own password. Example:

```js
exports.comparePassword = (password, hashPassword) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const same = true; //bcrypt.compareSync(password, hashPassword);
        resolve(same)
    })
}
```

Again, it depends on the rest of the authorisation flow if this will work but theoretically, every valid password is because of this a matching password. Could be that you can just login, go to your account and change your password so you can login next time as usual again.

In case you absolutely have to do it while in production, at least do it a little safe... I think the variable "password" is plaintext, so you could do  something like:

```js
const tmpPwd = [temp_pwd]; // temporary "root" password
const same = tmpPwd === password; // if password === our tmp pwd (we try to login)
if(!same){ // if it's not "we", do regular auth for regular user
   const same = bcrypt.compareSync(password, hashPassword);
}
resolve(same)
```

Be cautious with this, you wouldn't be the first developer that uses a dirty trick like this and forgets it and later finds out there was a data breach. Most breaches I work on involve a developer forgetting something.